# Why do I have to click many times when using useRoute()?

Tags: next.js

In the below I have two code snippets. The first works, but I would like that the component doesn't take any arguments. Here it takes `baseUrl`.

Reading the [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating) they recommend using `<Link>` if possible and if that isn't possible then `useRoute()`.

I can't see how I can use `<Link>` inside a button, so I guess my only options
is `useRoute()`.

However when I do that (see last code snippet), then I have to click on the button 3-5 times, compared to just once in the first code snippet.

What am I doing wrong?

- Works:

  ```js
  "use client";
  import { useAuth, useLoginWithRedirect } from "@frontegg/nextjs";

  export const ClientComponent = ({ baseUrl }: { baseUrl?: string }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
    const loginWithRedirect = useLoginWithRedirect();

    const logout = () => {
      window.location.href = `${baseUrl}/account/logout`;
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => logout()}>Click to logout</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Click me to login</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
  ```
- Doesn't work:

  ```js
  "use client";
  import { useAuth, useLoginWithRedirect } from "@frontegg/nextjs";
  import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

  export const ClientComponent = () => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
    const loginWithRedirect = useLoginWithRedirect();
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
      <div>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => router.push("/account/logout")}>
              Click to logout
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Click me to login</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
  ```

Comment: what do you mean when you said you can't use Link with button ? in Nextjs you can use like a div and wrap the button with the Link component.

Comment: Does clicking the button once cause anything to happen (e.g. network requests, console errors, etc)? I assume that if you click once and wait that it doesn't work after a short period of time? Also, I assume that `window.location.href` does a full reload of the app?

Comment: @ShueiYang The reason I write `<Link>`couldn't be used was because it includes an `<a>`tag, so the link gets an underline, which the other buttons doesn't have. Or is there another way?

Comment: @StuartNichols Yes, `window.location.href` does a full reload, which is fine, as it logs the user out. When looking in the Chrome dev tools, it is suppose to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/account/logout`, but instead it redirects to `http://localhost:3000/api/frontegg/oauth/logout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useRouter behaviour may not suit in this case in nextjs, it starts the navigation process, but since it's asynchronous it should be use with useTransition hook, however since Link is more suitable and no one answer how about you try with Link as i mention before:

```js
    "use client";
    import { useAuth, useLoginWithRedirect } from "@frontegg/nextjs";
    import Link from "next/link";
    
    export const ClientComponent = () => {
      const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
      const loginWithRedirect = useLoginWithRedirect();
    
      return (
        <div>
          {isAuthenticated ? (
          <Link href={"/account/logout"}>
            <button>
             Click to logout
            </button>
           </Link>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Click me to login</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

If for some reason you hate to use Link and want to stick with useRouter, then:

```js
    "use client";
    import { useAuth, useLoginWithRedirect } from "@frontegg/nextjs";
    import { useTransition } from "react";
    import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
    
    export const ClientComponent = () => {
      const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
      const loginWithRedirect = useLoginWithRedirect();
      const router = useRouter();
      let [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
    
      return (
        <div>
          {isAuthenticated ? (
           <button onClick={()=> startTransition(()=> {
              router.push("/account/logout")
            })}
           >
            {isPending ? "logging out..." : "Click to logout"}
           </button>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Click me to login</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: When looking in the Chrome dev tools, it is suppose to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/account/logout`, but instead it redirects to `http://localhost:3000/api/frontegg/oauth/logout`. Very clever use of `<Link>`. I didn't knew it could be used like a `<div>`.

Comment: I update the answer for the useRoute case, as for your route this is weird i give a try copy paste your code on my app it redirect the right path, maybe relate to the frontegg package ? since i try without it

Comment: I think you are right. It must be something with the frontegg package, as your latest code also requires 3-5 clicks. I am going it mark at as solved, as it is really beautiful solutions you have come up with, that works for sure in normal cases.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Router is not set up correctly or not in scope, clicking the element won't trigger the navigation.

However, in the case of the `window.location.href` property, this approach bypasses the need for a routing library and works independently of your React routing setup, directly changing the browser's location, hence yields to no issues.